# Use C-clamps in place of mounting clamps for truck cap/topper?

Tags: fastening

One friend that says c-clamps are the same thing. Another friend thinks I should drill holes for bolts (where I'd fasten them with wing nuts).

Are c-clamps good enough to secure a small truck's cap/topper?

Comment: What is a topper? What loads are likely? What is it being fastened to?

Comment: @SolarMike a "topper" is a light-weight aluminum or fiberglass cover that fits over the bed of a pickup truck. It sits on the side rails of the truck and rises (nearly) straight up to provide covered space in the bed that's (roughly) the same height as the cab. [One example brand's line](https://www.leer.com/Truck-Caps) (a major supplier in the US, but not the only one).

Comment: c-clamps are good enough if you do not drive the truck

Answer (score 1):

A large C-clamp is probably strong enough, but it is more likely to slip off. I would not use this method. You don't want to have to explain to an insurance company why your method failed and severely damaged several cars, or worse. Use the topper manufactures recommended method (probably bolts and some type of locking nut, not a wingnut).

Answer (score 1):

"Back in my day..."

In the mid-80s a lot of my friend's parents used C clamps for this purpose. However, trucks were used more for their hauling/working capabilities and less for their luxury/comfort capabilities, so there weren't quite the plethora of accessories that there are today.

To be honest, I wouldn't think that a purpose designed clamp would be notably more expensive than a c-clamp unless you're buying really cheap c-clamps whose strength might be questionable. It would have a wider base and would probably have rubber pads that would spread the clamping force over a wider area to improve the grip and reduce the possibility of damage to either the topper or the bed rim.

The c-clamp will, likely, take up more room extending into the bed of the truck, meaning that you're going to knock into it more often. This will hurt if you hit it, be an inconvenience if you're loading/unloading stuff, and possibly dent/scratch the truck.

The c-clamp *might* be more succeptible to working loose due to the vibration of driving down the road.

Drilling holes in the rim of the bed and the lip of the topper and installing bolts would give you a very secure method of attachment, especially if you used lock washers and/or thread locker. However, removing the cap wouldn't be nearly as convenient as with clamps of any sort - you'd need to keep the appropriate wrench(s) in the truck with you.

It's also a *great* way to increase the speed at which your bed rusts out, since you're drilling through the protective paint *and* galvanizing layer and directly exposing the inner steel to moisture. Price out replacement beds to find out just how much you don't want the bed rusting any earlier than necessary.

Comment: "purpose designed clamp" https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=pickup+truck+topper+clamps&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: @AlaskaMan yup. They are, essentially, c-clamps, but they've got grooves to grip the top and they're compact to minimize intrusion into the bed (and none seem to come with any rubber padding).